# Disable JSP Index Manager in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to disable the "JSP Index Manager" in Eclipse? I'm asking because certain actions that result in "Processing Build Path Changes" start a complete reindex. Due to the high number of JSPs it takes forever (~30 minutes).

Answer (score 2):

Preferences/Web/JSP Files and deactivate Include JSP matches in Java searches